# Regarding Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have been working on something and came across something interesting regarding interfaces. I think that is fairly common, but I am new to this. I just want to make sure if what I did is correct.

Let us Assume I am having an interface say B.

```
interface B {}.
```

I have a class A which implements B.

```
class A implements B { }.
```

Now let us say we have a Class C in which we use interface B.

```
class C {
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

we have another test class as follows:

```
public class TestAll {
    private final C c = new C();
    private final A a = new A();
    private final B b = null;
    void test123(){
        c.setB(a);//[1]
        c.setB(b);//[2]     
    }
}
```

So now my question is the method call [1] correct or wrong? If it is correct, i am sure it is one of the OOP concept, what is that? I am sorry if it is straight forward, I am new to all this java stuff.

Thank you.

Comment: A compiler can tell you if this is correct or not.

Comment: What do you mean, "correct"?  It works, and it's supposed to work.

Comment: Did you try this?  Was there an error?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it is correct. No error in compiler. but, I want to know if that is a right way to do. My bad. Wrong framing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces represent an abstract way to divide **What** a class can Do and **How** exactly the class will do it, since A implements B, that means that Class A "CAN" do what interface B contract offers, therefore `c.setB(a);//[1]` is 100% valid.

This method "setB(B b)" can be read as *give me something that can Do what B offers, no matter how*

.

**Ergo**: it is a valid method call.

the second call is more than obvious that it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the OOP concept is just Polymorphism. please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

B objects can have several forms and shapes i.e A, but it can be any other object that implements interface B.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, you can always pass a subtype (class A implements B) whereever you expect the inherited type (B).

However, in class B setB() you can treat the passed parameter as if it would be B (and you can not access to additional attributes or methods of class A).

I suggest you first implementing simpler real-life project with pure inheritance, without interfaces and abstract classes to get a grasp of this all.

For example, imagine you're modeling a Pub. In the Pub, there are Drinks what Human instances can consume.

```
class Drink {
   String name;
   double servingSize;

   public Drink(String name,double servingSize) {
       this.name=name;
       this.servingSize=servingSize;
   }
}

class Snaps extends Drink {
   public Snaps() {
       super("Finlandia Vodka",0,5);
   }
}

class Human {
    public void consume(Drink drink) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now your question is whether a Human can consume only a Drink instance, or also a descendant, so a Snaps? The answer is of course a Human can consume Snaps, as Snaps is a descendant of a Drink. Once the Human can consume a Drink, he can consume any Drink descendants.

I hope it makes things easier to understand. :)

Answer (score 0):

[1] is correct. Under the contra variance principle, you can always pass objects as parameters into a method that specifies the class of the object, or any parent class of that class, as an argument.